# .off('click') - but i want 'click' back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to do this. here it is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QGGhW/2/

but after i hit `not now`, it is no more clickable for the next textinput.

how can i do this? is there something like `.on('click');` again to append the click event back again?

appreciate any help.

Comment: you could also do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/QGGhW/3/  if this is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a registered handler, you need to pass the registered event handler instance also to the [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fn(){
        $(this).html('<textarea> </textarea><button class="test">save</button><button class="dont">not now</button>').off('click', fn);
    };
    $('#write_comment').on('click', fn);

    $('#write_comment').on('click','.test', function(){
        alert('testme');
    });
    $('#write_comment').on('click','.dont', function(){
        console.log('d')
        $('#write_comment').text('click me').on('click', fn);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uxfz8/1/)

Answer (score 2):

> is there something like `.on('click');` again to append the click event back again?

Yes. It is `.on('click', eventHandler)`.

See the jQuery documentation for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: can you pls see my problem in fiddle